# Docker exec on an intermediate build image doesn't work

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I am not sure what is going on here. It has worked in the past so I think I might just not understand what it happening.

I am building an image from a Dockerfile and would like to troubleshoot why its failing.

Example image

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN useradd app -G sudo
RUN apt-get update -f && apt-get install -f curl
```

So that fails with the out output

```
 Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 6cc0fc2a5ee3
Step 2 : RUN useradd app -G sudo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 550a41c97f96
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update -f && apt-get install -f curl
 ---> Running in aeb80950d7cc
E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -f && apt-get install -f curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

From what I have read and what Ive done in the past is use the image to look around and run commands

```
docker exec -it aeb80950d7cc bash
```

But this gives an error

```
Error response from daemon: Container aeb80950d7cc is not running
```

Im not sure why this isnt working. Im using osx and docker machine with virtual box too.

Comment: `docker exec` operates on running containers, not on images.  You would need to run the intermediate image (`docker run ... aeb80950d7cc ...`) first.

Comment: Docker run gives the message "unable to find the image ### locally"

Comment: @Matthew do you build with `--force-rm=true` because that will remove the intermediate containers even if the docker build fails

Comment: No the command I used to build is "docker build -t imagename ."

Comment: ahh, i see it. So you're running in aeb80950d7cc. which is created but fails to run. this layer never gets saved until the run command is completed. If you use `550a41c97f96` instead, then you can re-run the run command and see more detailed environment

Comment: It also helps to actually read the error message. ;) Try `apt-get -f update`, notice the position of `-f`.

Comment: @wrossmck I reran the build command, let it fail and used the hash that came up in the step before and docker run worked. So my problem is pretty much solved. And now Im unsure why docker exec has worked in the past.

Comment: @ErikDannenberg The apt-get typo was just an example for a simple failing build

Comment: @Matthew it's _possible_ that the container wouldn't get cleaned up in the past and would remain a zombie container until some later time (or never). Although that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

use `docker inspect aeb80950d7cc| grep Image`, and run with the given image_id

eg.
[image]